# Chatter Messenger is not visible in our sandbox

Tags: chatter

We have enabled chatter messenger in our sandbox, following the steps from below link,

https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?urlname=How-do-you-enable-Chatter-Messenger&language=en_US

Despite this we are not able to see the chatter window at right bottom of the page.

Answer (score 0):

There are two more links related to your link.

- When the organization-wide default for the user object is set to Private, User Sharing does not fully support these features. Therefore, organization needs to set OWD for user object to Public Read only.
- As per the Spring '16 release notes, [Chatter Messenger: Retiring in Spring ’17](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring16/release-notes/rn_chatter_messenger_eol.htm) and unavailable and no longer supported for new Salesforce organizations created after Spring '16.

I am sure your issue is related to any of these.